# Whats the simplest way to return all commits on git to master branch that have not been merged already?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, libgit2sharp

I'm using LigGit2Sharp.  I've tried using

```
foreach (Commit commit in repo.Commits)
{
    foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", commit.Sha, commit.MessageShort);
    }
}
```

However this shows all of the commits history...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create a filtered list (`ICommitLog`) between two `commit-ish` (commits, trees, tags, ...).

This is a example of getting all the commits between the tip of two branches; a "master" branch and a bug fix branch that has had changes made to it but not merged yet to "master":

```
public ICommitLog CommitList {
    get {
        var filter = new CommitFilter { 
            SortBy = CommitSortStrategies.Reverse | CommitSortStrategies.Time,
            Since = repo.Branches.Single (branch => branch.FriendlyName == "bugfix1234");
            Until = repo.Branches.Single (branch => branch.FriendlyName == "master");           
        };
        return repo.Commits.QueryBy (filter);
    }
}
```